# Using Akka to load balance HTTP SOAP request between multiple backend servers

Tags: load-balancing, akka, sticky

I am working on a project which has following requirements:

1. Perform sticky based load balancing(based on SOAP session ID) onto multiple backend servers.
2. Possibility to plugin my own custom based load balancer.
3. Easy to write and deploy.
4. A central configuration file(Possibly an XML), to take care of all the backend servers.
5. Easy extraction of a node from this configuration file(Possibly with xpath).

I tried working with camel for a while but, wasn't able to do perform certain task with it.
So thought of giving a try to Akka.
Will akka be possibly able to satisfy the above requirements?

If so is there a load balancing example in akka or proxy example?

Would really appreciate some feedbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do everything you've described with Akka.

You don't mention what language you're working with, Scala or Java.  I've included links to the Scala documentation.

Before you do anything with Akka you HAVE TO read the documentation and understand how Akka works.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/

Doing so, you'll find Akka is perfect for the project you've described with some minor caveats.

Once you read the documentation the following answers should make a lot of sense.

> Perform sticky based load balancing(based on SOAP session ID) onto multiple backend servers.

Load balancing is already part of the framework (it's called Routing in Akka http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/scala/routing.html) and Remoting (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/scala/remoting.html) will take care of the backend servers.  You can easily combine the two.

To my knowledge the idea of sticky load balancing is not a part of Akka but I can envision this being accomplished with a Map using the session ID as the key and the Actor name (or path) as the value.  A quick actorFor will take care of the rest.  Not well thought out but should give you a good idea of where to start.

> Possibility to plugin my own custom based load balancer.

Refer to the Routing documentation.

> Easy to write and deploy.

This depends on your aptitude and effort but after you read certain parts of the documentation you should be build a proof of concept in a couple of hours.

Deployment can be a bit frustrating mostly because the documentation isn't really great with respect to deploying Akka networks with remote components.  However, there are enough examples  on the web that you can figure out how to get it done...eventually.  Once you do it once it's no big deal.

> A central configuration file(Possibly an XML), to take care of all the backend servers.

Akka uses Typesafe Config (https://github.com/typesafehub/config) which is a lot easier to work with than XML (but I hate XML so take that with a grain of salt).  As far as a central configuration, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish but it sounds like something that can be solved using remote actor creation. Again, see the Remoting documentation.

> Easy extraction of a node from this configuration file(Possibly with xpath).

Akka provides a lookup method .actorFor.  There's no need to go to the configuration file once the system is up and running.

> If so is there a load balancing example in akka or proxy example?

Google is your friend.